# Automatically import CSV without duplicate images

Tags: php, magento

A manufacturer with products for my Magento shop makes a CSV. I want to integrate that CSV in my Magento shop to run every hour automatically. But I think when I import the CSV every hour, the images will show multiple in the product overview, because the images are added every time the CSV is imported. Because the CSV is delivered by the manufacturer with new products, I can't edit it and delete the image collumn for already imported products. Or is that possible with PHP?

Do you have an idea how I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: How you import this ? From the Magento import tool or with a custom script ?
You need to add a check : if image exist do nothing else import image

Comment: I will import this with the Magento import tool (if possible) and edit the manufacturer CSV with PHP to make it fit for Magento. Yes, I need that button! :) How can I make that?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to run a scheduled automated script?

Here is a little script to find and delete all duplicate images in Magento.

http://www.aadil.co/how-to-delete-duplicate-product-images-in-magento/